# How to point domain to url on external site using nameservers

Tags: .htaccess, nameservers

Here is what I want to accomplish.

I have domain A which I want to update the nameservers to use the custom nameservers setup on domain B (i.e. ns1.domainb.com and ns2.domainb.com).

Then, when users go to domainA.com I want it to take them to domainB.com/domainA

How can I accomplish this? Can't I accomplish this via HTACCESS files on domainB?

Comment: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domainB.com/domainA$1 [R=301,L]` in domianA.com's .htaccess. Do both domain's point to the same server location?

Comment: I don't want to do anything on domainA.com except update the nameservers. I don't own domainA it's actually a users website. I'm trying to get it so whenever anyone visits domainA.com it takes them to a specific page on domainB.com. I've already accomplished this via forwarding (301 redirect), but I know it can be done with nameservers too. Look at the domain parking websites. They require you to just update your nameserver to be theirs. How do they do that?

Comment: Set the DNS of domainA.com to point to the IP address of domainB.com's server. In the root of domainB.com, create an htaccess rule to redirect to /domainA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When users go to domainA.com I want it to take them to
>   domainB.com/domainA

This solution explains how to achieve:

**example.com** --> domainB.com/**example.com**

### DNS records and .htaccess

First, set the DNS of *domainA.com* to point to the IP address of *domainB.com*'s server. In the root of *domainB.com*, create an *.htaccess* file with a rule to redirect/rewrite *domainA.com* requests to *domainB.com/domainA*. There are two methods and outcomes.

### Method 1 - Silently rewrite the URI request

User navigates to http://example.com, browser shows http://example.com.

Set these .htaccess rules in the root of domainB.com:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Check that the request is NOT from domainB.com, e.g. domainA
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !domainB\.com$ [NC]

# Capture the top-level domainA name
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+?)$

# Check that we are not already requesting a valid file or directory
# This prevents inserting the subdirectory name into an already valid path
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite requests with the domainA subdirectory
RewriteRule (.*) /%1/$1 [L]
```

### Method 2 - Explicitly force a redirect to the new location

User navigates to http://example.com, browser shows http://domainB.com/example.com.

Set these .htaccess rules in the root of domainB.com:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Check that the request is NOT from domainB.com, e.g. domainA
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !domainB\.com$ [NC]

# Capture the top-level domainA name
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+?)$

# Force a 301 redirect to the new URI
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domainB.com/%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

### Customization

At the time of this writing, you can test and modify (most) *.htaccess* rules to support your customized requirements here: http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

Here are tips and tricks to achieve further customization: http://mod-rewrite-cheatsheet.com/

Comment: How can I make that dynamic so I don't have to put a row in my htaccess for every domain I want to do this for? Is there a way to make it work where the htaccess file rule could be HTTP_HOST != domainb.com, if so then rewrite to domainb.com/domaina?

Comment: Yes it can in fact. :) I'll update my answer with your new requirement

Comment: Thanks Drakes. It's almost 1am for me now. Let me try this tomorrow and if it works I'll accept your answer. Thanks a bunch for your help! I'll post back if I hit any issues.

Comment: I've rewritten my answer to be a complete solution. Please let me know how it works out for you

Comment: The resulting URL after the rewrite should be domainB.com/domainA.com

Comment: No problem. You want to keep the extension in the subdirectory. Simple fix. I'll update it

Comment: The http request is rewritten and the domainA request will transparently take the visitor to domainB.com/domainA.com/. This is not a redirect. It's a transparent request rewrite that happens on domainB.com. The browser will see the url http://domainA.com, but the action will happen on domainB.com

Comment: You are very close. With the way its written right now this is the output URL its producing: http://domainsA.com/domainA.com/

Comment: I tried tweaking the htaccess code but i was unsuccessful. :( the closet I got was domainA.com/domainB.com/domainA.com lol which is all kinds of wrong. lol

Comment: Be advised that http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ can't handle some my script related to filename. Those are important. I highly recommend running the htaccess on a local test server as I have for your case

Comment: Also, URL rewriting and redirecting are two different things. Do you want the user to be **aware** he is on domainB.com?

Comment: My second case will force a 301 redirect. The user will know he has been redirected. However, htaccess.madewithlove.be will show you exactly what you want.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks Drakes. You rock! Your entry is a really solid guide now too. Looks great. I'm going to try method 1 on my own server tonight. Accepting answer as I just tested method 2 and it works.

Comment: I'm still having issues. Its testing out right like I said on the tester, but when I put it into my htaccess file for domainB.com its going to a page that say "This webpage is unavailable" when I go to domainA.com in the browser. This is from the message details -> "The server at achilliescontracting.com can't be found, because the DNS lookup failed."

Comment: I'm pretty confident the issue is not with your htaccess code and its an issue with my custom nameserver setup. So ignore this. Thanks again for a great answer to my question Drakes. Take care. I'll have to sort this out on the NS side of things now.